# Maven plugins showing each plugin twice in Intellij

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have the following pom.xml file.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.rei.eventplan</groupId>
    <artifactId>event-plan-lambda-aptos-add-product</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>EP Txt Event Handler</name>
    <url>https://git.rei.com/projects/EP19/repos/ep-txt-event-handler/browse</url>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.8</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws.serverless</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-serverless-java-container-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-dynamodb</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.551</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-secretsmanager</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.316</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>24.0-jre</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.transaction-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>shaded-jar</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>shade</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <artifactSet>
                                        <excludes>
                                            <exclude>org.apache.tomcat.embed:*</exclude>
                                        </excludes>
                                    </artifactSet>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>assembly-zip</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <!-- don't build a jar, we'll use the classes dir -->
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.1.1</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>default-jar</id>
                                <phase>none</phase>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <!-- select and copy only runtime dependencies to a temporary lib folder -->
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.1.1</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}${file.separator}lib</outputDirectory>
                                    <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.1.0</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>zip-assembly</id>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>single</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
                                    <descriptors>
                                        <descriptor>src${file.separator}assembly${file.separator}bin.xml</descriptor>
                                    </descriptors>
                                    <attach>false</attach>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>database-update</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                        <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.6.3</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <propertyFile>src/main/resources/liquibase/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>process-resources</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>update</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>sonar</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.sonarsource.scanner.maven/sonar-maven-plugin -->
                        <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
                        <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.6.0.1398</version>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>jacoco</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jacoco/jacoco-maven-plugin -->
                            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>0.8.5</version>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

For some reason, the plugins tab in Intellij showing each plugin twice. Following is a screenshot:
[image]

So if you see, the clean plugin is showing twice and others likewise. So is it a bug of intellij or some setup issue in the pom.xml? Kindly note I also have maven installed in my local system.

Comment: It seems to be related to Intellj. Try to remove the "EP Txt Event Handler" project from "Maven Project" window right-clicking on it and then on "Remove Projects" and then importing it again translating with your pom.xml file on "Maven Project" window again. Do this fix your issue?

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam Yes that solution helped, thank you. Can you please mark this question as duplicate and close it?